# R reading numeric data as non-numeric

Tags: r

I have downloaded a .csv file from the World Bank's databank containing USA's gdp per capita growth (annual %) from 1964 to 2022. After reading the file and saving the values in a variable, R seems to believe that the data is non-numeric, as per the following errors:

```
> mean(gdp)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(gdp) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

> round(gdp)
Error in Math.data.frame(list(4.34054896320299, 5.07809761043293, 5.27711385836413,  : 
non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: 38, 39, 59
```

However, the variable clearly has numeric data:

```
> gdp
                                                                   
1 4.340549 5.078098 5.277114 1.389951 3.758819 2.09737 -1.438451 1.9956
                                                                      
1 4.138097 4.642156 -1.445134 -1.184581 4.391463 3.577147 4.422985 2.033887
                                                                     
1 -1.209298 1.53632 -2.73457 3.631979 6.312168 3.250656 2.510886 2.538624
                                                                     
1 3.235416 2.698167 0.7414861 -1.4342 2.096613 1.405709 2.760882 1.468718
                                                              
1 2.572259 3.197212 3.270511 3.597985 2.925441 -0.0399197287893003
                                                                     
1 0.756774050858581 1.91648 2.895848 2.533784 1.796486 1.04493 -0.8203679
                                                                        
1 -3.450016 1.860292 0.8145194 1.533102 1.138692 1.540381 1.953004 0.9333754
                                                            
1 1.597136 2.404868 1.829668 -3.700953 5.779548 1.55148744876492
```

What is causing this error?

---

**How the data was downloaded:** by accessing the [WB's databank](https://databank.worldbank.org/reports.aspx?source=2&series=NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG&country=USA#) and selecting the following options:

- Country: USA
- Series: GDP per capita growth (annual %)
- Time: from 1964 to 2022 (both inclusive)

Then the data can be downloaded by clicking on "Download options" and "CSV". The file should look like so:

[image]

---

**How the data was read:** after deleting the B, C, and D columns and renaming the file to 'gdp.csv', I open R in the corresponding directory and run

```
> data = read.csv("gdp.csv")
> gdp = unname(data[1,-1])
```

---

**Output of some commands asked for in the comments:**

```
> dput(gdp)
structure(list(4.34054896320299, 5.07809761043293, 5.27711385836413, 
1.38995128628369, 3.75881936763187, 2.09736970647879, -1.43845053330176, 
1.99560023463674, 4.13809677493917, 4.64215574445912, -1.44513434368933, 
-1.18458141215473, 4.39146286737468, 3.57714670648173, 4.42298460692567, 
2.03388706463849, -1.20929826319077, 1.53632028085542, -2.73456973098722, 
3.631979295881, 6.31216765588185, 3.25065642338708, 2.51088596744542, 
2.53862353656405, 3.23541610899424, 2.69816667236526, 0.74148609960973, 
-1.43420012525736, 2.09661276602233, 1.40570856500528, 2.76088229716902, 
1.46871823407399, 2.57225920399024, 3.1972120547039, 3.27051107297336, 
3.59798501816873, 2.92544098347776, "-0.0399197287893003", 
"0.756774050858581", 1.91648045091225, 2.89584777850045, 
2.53378411366741, 1.79648632582968, 1.04493013677586, -0.820367898524154, 
-3.45001592321435, 1.86029167805893, 0.814519357932042, 1.53310203539129, 
1.13869234666606, 1.54038064866397, 1.95300411790625, 0.933375361665711, 
1.59713559028371, 2.40486787201, 1.82966838809384, -3.70095252825833, 
5.77954841835778, "1.55148744876492"), row.names = 4L, class = "data.frame")

> str(gdp)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  59 variables:
 $ : num 4.34
 $ : num 5.08
 $ : num 5.28
 [...]
 $ : num 2.93
 $ : chr "-0.0399197287893003"
 $ : chr "0.756774050858581"
 $ : num 1.92
 [...]
 $ : num 5.78
 $ : chr "1.55148744876492"
```

where I have ommitted most lines starting with `num`, as I'm guessing the ones beginning with `chr` are the issue.

Comment: Can you share the top 10 or so lines of the raw file? We have no way of knowing how you downloaded it, what it was, what it became, and how you read it in.

Comment: Hi Sam, two quick requests: 1. could you please post a link to the worldbank csv or post the output of `dput(gdp)`? 2. could you post the output of `str(gdp)`?

Comment: One clue as to what is going on is the the output you posted for `gdp` shows an index number of 1 on every row.  That makes me suspicious that the data file is tab delimited rather than comma separated.  You could try opening the file with `read.table("youfile.txt", sep="")` instead of `read.csv()`

Comment: I second the request for str(gdp). Also, when you import a file you can specify how you want the data to be read (ex). 
```{r}
fakedata = read.csv(file = "Fakedata.csv", colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "character", "numeric")) ```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `round` on a complete `data.frame`, which is generally fine assuming that all columns are numeric. For instance,

```r
sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)
#  mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb 
# TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE 
round(head(mtcars, 3))
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110    4  3   16  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110    4  3   17  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710     23   4  108  93    4  2   19  1  1    4    1
```

However, your frame is *not* all numeric:

```r
sapply(gdp, is.numeric)
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [27]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [53]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So you cannot do a math-operation on the frame-as-a-whole.

The columns that are strings look like they should be numbers, so I suspect that something in your data import or earlier in your data-processing *corrupted* those columns. While we can mend it here and likely not lose much precision, this is certainly not ideal, and it is not always a lossless process ... so go back and fix whatever broke the data.

There are a few ways to work around this:

1. Mend those columns, assuming that columns 38, 39, and 59 are *supposed* to be numeric:

   ```r
   gdp[,c(38, 39, 59)] <- lapply(gdp[,c(38, 39, 59)], as.numeric)
   round(gdp)
   #                                                                                                                                 
   # 4 4 5 5 1 4 2 -1 2 4 5 -1 -1 4 4 4 2 -1 2 -3 4 6 3 3 3 3 3 1 -1 2 1 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 0 1 2 3 3 2 1 -1 -3 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 -4 6 2
   ```

   This rounded each of your 59 columns.
2. Don't mend those columns (back to the original `gdp` here), just round the other 56 columns:

   ```r
   round(gdp[,-c(38, 39, 59)])
   #                                                                                                                           
   # 4 4 5 5 1 4 2 -1 2 4 5 -1 -1 4 4 4 2 -1 2 -3 4 6 3 3 3 3 3 1 -1 2 1 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 2 3 3 2 1 -1 -3 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 -4 6
   ```

   If you intend to round and save back into `gdp` (overwriting the raw numbers), then you can do

   ```r
   gdp[,-c(38, 39, 59)] <- round(gdp[,-c(38, 39, 59)])
   ```

   recognizing that the three columns are still strings (and not rounded).
3. Go back earlier in your pipe, either at the import or some other intermediate operation, and fix the source of the problem instead of mending it here. I really prefer this to the first two, over to you.

---

Data

```r
gdp <- structure(list(4.34054896320299, 5.07809761043293, 5.27711385836413, 1.38995128628369, 3.75881936763187, 2.09736970647879, -1.43845053330176, 1.99560023463674, 4.13809677493917, 4.64215574445912, -1.44513434368933, -1.18458141215473, 4.39146286737468, 3.57714670648173, 4.42298460692567, 2.03388706463849, -1.20929826319077, 1.53632028085542, -2.73456973098722, 3.631979295881, 6.31216765588185, 3.25065642338708, 2.51088596744542, 2.53862353656405, 3.23541610899424, 2.69816667236526, 0.74148609960973,      -1.43420012525736, 2.09661276602233, 1.40570856500528, 2.76088229716902, 1.46871823407399, 2.57225920399024, 3.1972120547039, 3.27051107297336, 3.59798501816873, 2.92544098347776, "-0.0399197287893003", "0.756774050858581", 1.91648045091225, 2.89584777850045, 2.53378411366741, 1.79648632582968, 1.04493013677586, -0.820367898524154, -3.45001592321435, 1.86029167805893, 0.814519357932042, 1.53310203539129, 1.13869234666606, 1.54038064866397, 1.95300411790625, 0.933375361665711, 1.59713559028371,      2.40486787201, 1.82966838809384, -3.70095252825833, 5.77954841835778, "1.55148744876492"), row.names = 4L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: While the first option does allow me to later round `gdp`, it still does not allow me to compute the mean. Do you happen to know how to resolve this?

Comment: `round` works on a frame, it does what one might expect; `mean` requires a vector and does not work on list-like objects, so you'd need to unlist it first, such as `mean(unlist(mtcars))` or `mean(unlist(round(gdp[,-c(38, 39, 59)])))` or such.